# mailto: put in the mail body a link but not showing the url

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mailto

It's about the fact that I don't want to show the full link in an email,
but a short text where the link is stored.
If you click on "Open Link" you should be redirected to the URL.
The text "Open Link" should also be bold.
I am using Angular.

```
<a
href="mailto:test@test.com?subject={{this.mailService().template(receiver).subject}}&body={{this.mailService().template(receiver).body}}" target="_top">
```

```
public template(receiver) {
return new Mail(

`Subject: Open Link`,

`Body:` +
`Open Link`
);
```

}

Outlook opens for me and the subject and body text is displayed.
I just want the link not to be fully displayed in the subject and body, but to be stored behind a text.

As seen here:

[image]

I've also tried it with HTML code in my template method. HTML is not recognized.

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Open Link</a>
```

I've already googled but found nothing about my problem.
https://www.google.com/search?q=mailto+hyperlink+with+body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, because the mailto link can only contain plain text, not HTML.

[From RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#:%7E:text=The%20%22body%22%20field,general%20MIME%0A%20%20%20bodies.):

> The "body" field value is intended to contain the content for the
> first text/plain body part of the message. The "body" pseudo header
> field is primarily intended for the generation of short text messages
> for automatic processing (such as "subscribe" messages for mailing
> lists), not for general MIME bodies.

Comment: Can you think of an alternative solution to mailto?